# How do I create a lookup column using EF?

Tags: entity-framework

I used to know how to do this, but I guess I forgot, I want to add a column in my model that references another column in another table, since its value should always be one of the values in the staff table..

something like this..

```
        public class Customer 
       ( public list<Staff> list{get;set;}
          ..) 
        public class Staff
       ( public int ID {get;set:}...)

this class also contains name and that is the value I want to pull into this             other entity if that makes sense..
```

Comment: You're looking for a Navigation Property https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj713564(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the pointer on a tight deadline and need to show a demo by the end of the week.